# How to echo extra column with number in each row?

Tags: php, html

I have generated table using html,mysql and php. I want to generate an extra column and have a number inserted in each row of this new column.

```
echo "<table border='1'>
          <tr>
              <th>Rank</th>
              <th>owner ID</th>
              <th>Total</th>
          </tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . '1' . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['owner_id'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['total'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Now the Rank is the extra column I have generated and where the 1 is, I can currently see it in all rows of this new column. How do I get the other rows to be 2,3,4 ect? I have attempted to insert a new row and inserted a 2 after the "'1'." but this just makes the table loose its structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Rank</th>
<th>owner ID</th>
<th>Total</th>
</tr>";
$i = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {
$i++;
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $i . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['owner_id'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['total'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: ah Thanks Bogdan! it works will accept answer in a few minutes due to stackoverflow rules.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help. A proper explanation [would greatly improve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions. Please edit your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    @$i++;
    echo "<tr>
            <td>" . $i . "</td>
        </tr>";
}
```

It is ONLY an alternative, but it's nearly the same thing like above. No need to declare the `$i` before. Just use it right inside the loop with a `@` in front to prevent an error message. Do it only, if you know the consequences when errors occur.